Some internal/external websites not loading in selenium/standalone-chrome and works fine with selenium/standalone-firefox
I am trying to setup selenium automation framework which executes in docker. However some specific web applications that we are testing not loading in chrome remote browser. (works fine with selenium/standalone-firefox)
docker-compose.yml
chrome:
image: selenium/standalone-chrome
volumes:
- /dev/shm:/dev/shm
Tried with disabling some option related to certificates.
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
         options = new ChromeOptions();
         String hubUrl="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        options.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.merge(dc);
         WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), options);
         this.setDriver(driver);

        this.getDriver().navigate().to("sample website");

the URL is loaded in chrome browser in docker, however website is not displayed.
Note: many other urls (like www.google.com" loading fine without any issues)

you should include the exception(s) you receive.  What language is used here?  JS?

no exceptions. remote chrome in docker loading with url and white screen displayed and loading not getting completed. (no issue when running with chrome driver in local) we are suing java selenium.

you might try with driver.get(URL); (should be pretty much the same thing, but worth a shot)  Otherwise this sounds like a driver/browser version mismatch.  (or a browser that's trying to update itself when you launch it from the driver...)

See here for upgrading browser/driver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium?tab=readme-ov-file#upgrade-browser-version-in-the-images
